# Using jQuery removeData() with nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery `data()` function to store data on a series of divs in a format similar to:

```
{ 
    options: {
        example: {
            option_1: {
                value: "example 1"
            },
            option_2: {
                value: "example 2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can add new keys and update the data, e.g.

```
$("#mydiv").data('options',{'example':{} });    // the object is already created in the live version
$("#mydiv").data('options')['example']['option_3'] = { value: "example 3" };
```

But when I come to use removeData(), FireBug tells me that the key is undefined, e.g.

```
$("#mydiv").removeData('options')['example']['option_2'];
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You're not actually adding data when you think you are. For starters, the value you're setting must be a second argument to the `.data` method.

Comment: @Blazemonger: He is, *if* he has previously added the object using `.data('options', { ... })`, which I think he did.

Comment: You're correct, the object already exists - have updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.removeData(name)`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) removes the previously stored data with the given `name`, and returns a *jQuery* object. In your scenario, you don't want the remove the entire `options` object, just a specific property of it, so you should be using `delete` instead:

```
delete $("#mydiv").data('options')['example']['option_2'];
```